# Select neighbouring cells of a cell with a specific value in excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula

I have a data set in excel with four columns;

Username, Computer, Department information

I have used a filter to select all unique usernames in the data set, then have used counif() to count how many times the username occurs in the data set - This works fine.

Now I want to search the original data set for every time a specific username appears and when it does, I want to select the 'information' cell to that relevant row. So the output will be an array rather than one value,

example,

```
Username|Information
A            1
A            2
B            3
A            4
D            5
```

So if I use my function to search for all values from 'information' with username A, I want this to output,

```
Information
1
2
4
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about just using a filter to only show Username=A entries? It'll allow you to easily select (and thus reference) the needed entries.

Comment: I'm curious about this array output you're looking for.  Should it be a variable in VBA?  If so, can you tag this question with VBA and excel-VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one method that doesn't involve VBA.  It may not be practical for your needs though.

1. Make a pivot table based on your data
2. Add **Username** to the Filter
3. Add **Information** as a Row
4. Change the Filter from *(All)* to your desired username.

If you need to rerun the underlying dataset, just right click to refresh the pivot table.